# How to filter seq of n-tuples with n-arg predicate?

Tags: clojure

Suppose I have a function f which returns a sequence of n-tuples and a predicate p which takes n arguments - how do I filter f to obtain a sequence just containing those tuples for which p applied to each element of the tuple is true?

For example, say f is defined to return a sequence of pairs

```
(defn f [] (for [a (range 1 10) b (range 1 10)] [a b]))
```

and p takes two arguments and returns true if they are equal

```
(defn p [a b] (= a b))
```

I want to do something like this

```
(filter p (f))
```

But the compiler throws an ArityException because p takes two arguments and each element in the sequence is considered one thing (despite being a pair).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing `apply`. It applies a given function to a list of arguments as though they were individual. So, `(f 0 1)` and `(apply f [0 1])` are equivalent for most practical purposes. In your case, it would be:

```
(filter #(apply p %) (f))
```